# show that every nearly compact space may not be compact space

Tags: general-topology

I am learning about the compact space and nearly compact space.I know that every compact space is nearly compact space but the converse is not true in general.  So i need an example of nearly compact space which is not compact space.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll give you an example and leave the proof to you. Let

$$L=\left\{\left\langle\frac1m,0\right\rangle:m\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\quad\text{and}\quad D=\left\{\left\langle\frac1m,\frac1n\right\rangle:m,n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;,$$

let $p=\langle 0,0\rangle$, and let $X=\{p\}\cup L\cup D$. $L\cup D$ is an open subset of $X$, and its subspace topology from $X$ is the one that it inherits from the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R^2$: the points of $D$ are isolated, and the points $\left\langle\frac1m,\frac1n\right\rangle$ converge to $\left\langle\frac1m,0\right\rangle$ as $n$ increases. Finally, for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$B_k=\{p\}\cup\left\{\left\langle\frac1m,\frac1n\right\rangle\in D:m\ge k\right\}\;.$$

The resulting space is Hausdorff and not regular, so it cannot be compact, but it is nearly compact. In case you get completely stuck trying to prove that $X$ is nearly compact, I’ve left a small hint in the spoiler-protected block below.

> For each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, $\operatorname{cl}B_k$ is open, and its complement is compact.

Comment: Give an another example