# Show that every paracompact space is nearly paracompact but the converse is not true

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-groups, separation-axioms

I am learning about the para-compact space and nearly para-compact space. I know that every nearly para-compact space is para-compact space but the converse is not true in general. So i need an example of para-compact space which is not nearly para-compact space.

Answer (score 1):

You have it backwards: every paracompact space is nearly paracompact, but there are nearly paracompact spaces that are not paracompact. One of them is the space that I described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1696886/12042). Since it is Hausdorff but not regular, it is not paracompact. The proof that it is nearly paracompact is virtually identical to the proof that it is nearly compact.